# hwo to install .net 6 on linux debian 11?

Tags: .net, linux, installation, sdk, debian

i want to install dot net v6 on Linux Debian 11 . i download .net from Microsoft and get a .tar file from that .now i want to install all the .net (Runtime , sdk, compiler ,...).
i try extract folder but i can't install that.
there was many folder in extract file . i don't know how can i do.

some body can help me??
thank you??   [image]

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/linux ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install adding the .net repository manually. Here are the commands to follow:

```
wget https://packages.microsoft.com/config/debian/11/packages-microsoft-prod.deb -O packages-microsoft-prod.deb


sudo dpkg -i packages-microsoft-prod.deb

rm packages-microsoft-prod.deb
```

Run Update and also install tool for HTTPS support

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install -y apt-transport-https
```

And then install the package

```
sudo apt install dotnet-sdk-6.0
sudo apt-get install aspnetcore-runtime-6.0
sudo apt-get install dotnet-runtime-6.0
```

However, if you want to install by .tar.gz file, you need to follow this steps in a microsoft site:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/linux-scripted-manual#manual-install